# Preventing duplicate contact during record creation rule

Tags: dynamics-365

I have a setup which currently performs;

1. Import Data which create a dump into an activity queue
2. Record creation rule creates a contact and related case
   All works great!

however in terms of 2) i know duplicates are being created based on a custom field (new_contactid) is an exact match.

I have tried both duplicate detection rules and alternate keys and neither work as in the contact record is always created, assume limitation of record creation? i've ensured the duplicate detection rule is set on record create/update.

My other issue is i need to relate the case to either the newly created contact (which works great now) or regarding an existing contact.

I think what i ideally need is a custom WF step which checks for a duplicate contact; and if duplicate found return that existing contact - or creates a new contact - so when i create the case it can set the regarding accordingly (to either existing or newly created)

Thanks for any direction
Rich

Answer (score 0):

decided to go with a plugin which basically allows the duplicates to be created.
On the record creation rule (second step) i create the case (with regarding contact) and call a child workflow.
Child WF calls a plugin passing in the unique new_contactid as param;
plugins checks whether duplicate and merges (preserving any data that the new contact does not have)
All works well!

Cheers